# How do I find the structure that is pointing to the current structure in C?

Tags: c

I have an array of structures called box_pool. In this array each structure points to two other structures in order to create some organisation (I am creating a binary search tree). But what if I currently have a structure that I want to delete, but in order to do that I need to redirect the pointer of the previous structure to the next structure. How could I do that?

Comment: What is your own thinking? There really is no magic solution...

Comment: The only real possibilities are to do a reverse lookup (i.e. scan through the array to find what you're looking for), or have backlinks (so those other two structures have an extra pointer back into the array).

Answer (score 2):

You need to visit the structure starting from the root, there is no other simple way unless you store bidirectional links, so that you have

```
struct node
{
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
  struct node* parent;
}
```

This will help finding where the `node` is stored but will complicate things as you will have to keep `parent` updated, and waste some space. It's a typical trade-off.